# NoSuchElementException with java.util.scanner in school project

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am working on a school project. I have all the functionality working, I made it on Eclipse and it runs very well but when I submit the project through Mimir which is an online tool to grade your project, during deposits and withdraws it gives the following error:

```
Enter the amount you want to Deposit :$Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

13 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
14 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
15 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2345)
16 at BankAccount.deposit(BankAccount.java:24)
17 at SavingsAccountDemo.main(SavingsAccountDemo.java:30)
```

The project does says the following: Please make sure that your classes throw appropriate exceptions when an attempt is made to insert invalid data.

I tried to add the try and catch with `java.util.InputMismatchException e` and `java.util.NoSuchElementException` but it doesn't seem to be fixing it. I think it's because the userInput is a double and they are entering something different. Any ideas how can I fix that? I am going crazy, been trying to fix it for hours. Here is the code:

```
///SavingsAccountDemo class
import java.util.*;
public class SavingsAccountDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    double startingBalance;
    double interestRate;
    String userInput;
            
    System.out.print("Enter beginning balance :$");
    startingBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.print("Enter interest rate(whole number) :%");
    interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    
    double bal = startingBalance;
    double rate = interestRate;
    
    BankAccount ba = new BankAccount(startingBalance, interestRate);
    BankDemo sv = new BankDemo(bal, rate);
    
    while(startingBalance > -1) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter D for deposit" + "\nEnter W to Withdraw" + "\nEnter B for Balance" + 
                                "\nEnter M for Monthly Process" + "\nEnter E to Exit");
            userInput = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
            
            if("d".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.deposit();
            } else if("w".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.withdraw();
            } else if("b".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.totalBalance();
            } else if("m".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.monthlyProcess();
            } else if("e".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.exit();
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Error, option not valid\n");
            }
        }
        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.print("Error");
        }
    }
}

}
///BankAccount class
import java.util.*;
public class BankAccount {
protected double balance;
protected double numDeposits;
protected double numWithdrawals;
protected double annualRate;
protected double monthlyServCharg;
protected boolean active;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public BankAccount(double startingBalance, double interestRate) {
    balance = startingBalance;
    annualRate = interestRate /= 100.0;
    if(balance < 25) {
        active = false;
    } else
        active = true;
}
public void deposit() {
    try {
    double valueD;
    
    System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to Deposit :$");
    valueD = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if(valueD < 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
    }
    if( balance + valueD >= 25 && !active) {
        System.out.print("Your account is now ACTIVE\n");
        active = true;      
    }
    balance += valueD;
    numDeposits++;
    } 
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e){
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }
}
public void withdraw() {
    try {
        double valueW;
        
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to withdraw :$");
        valueW = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if(valueW < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
        }
        balance -= valueW;
        numWithdrawals++;
        if(balance < 0) {
            System.out.print("ERROR: Transaction declined!! This transaction will cause overdraft or zero balance\n");
            balance += valueW;
        } else if(balance <= 25 && active) {
            System.out.print("Your balance is less than minimum balance. Your account is now INACTIVE\n");
            active = false;
            }
        if(numWithdrawals > 4) {
            balance --;
            System.out.print("You have exceeded monthly limit of withdrawals. Fee of $1 charged\n");
        }
    } 
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    
}
public void totalBalance() {
    System.out.printf("Your Balance is: %.2f\n", balance);
}
public void calcInterest() {
    double monRate = annualRate / 12;
    double monInt = balance * monRate;
    balance += monInt;
}
public void monthlyProcess() {
    calcInterest();
    balance -= monthlyServCharg;
    numWithdrawals = 0;
    numDeposits = 0;
    monthlyServCharg = 0;
    System.out.printf("Your Balance after Monthly process is: %.2f\n", balance);
}

public void exit() {
    totalBalance();
    System.out.print("Thank you. Bye");
}
}
```

Comment: Before making any actions, add verifications for  `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` check that `keyboard` value is not null, and only when you checked that it is required type proceed with that value

Comment: @Tom Ronaldo your code is working fine for both Deposit and Withdrawal, can share the inputs used  to reproduce the error

Comment: @sanjeevRm these are the input cases they used: 1000
2 9
3 X
4 D
5 -1
6 W
7 -1
8 B
9 M
10 E
I tried them all and works in eclipse but I have read that there are sometimes problems with online editor with input

Comment: I got it to work, I had to add `if(sc.hasNext())` before getting the input

Answer (score 0):

When scanning an input with `Scanner`, the expected result is always a `String`.
Therefore, you have to check if the field is a `double` before assuming it is. You can use a cast and check with a `try` `catch` if casting raises an `NumberFormatException` error. If it is the case, the input is not valid. Otherwise, you can use that newly casted `double` in your program.

Comment: calling that function will assume that the input is a valid `double`. However, you needed to  catch exceptions so it is not good practice to do that with `nextDouble()`.